# Does MariaDB Connector 3.0.7 support Aurora MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, amazon-aurora

According to this article https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-connector-j-303-release-notes/ Mariadb removed support for aurora in version 3.0.3,

> Specific support for aurora has been removed, since Issues were piling
> up without the community proposing any PR for them and without access
> for us to test those modifications.

Anyone know if this support is enabled in later versions? We are using 3.0.7 and don't see any issues connecting to aurora db.

Answer (score 1):

Aurora plugin for MariaDB Connector/C is no longer supported. The status of the plugin was "experimental" and I removed the plugin in version 3.2.0, so it still exists in 3.0 and 3.1 but not in later versions.

Since the internal plugin API didn't change, it should be possible to use the plugin from 3.1 also in 3.3 (I never tested it).

Comment: Did you migrate to a different DB Connector? OR you continue to use on a lower version?

Comment: I'm the maintainer of MariaDB Connector/C.